# Excel VBA Open 1 CSV file

Tags: vba, excel, csv

Using Excel 2010, I am trying to add a code that will open up the file select window for the user to select the CSV file he wants to open.

My code is below:

```
Dim OpenThisFile
OpenThisFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
```

This was just taken from one of my old VBA files, this has worked before. Currently though, when the VBA reads the 2nd line it opens up the file select window but as soon as I select a CSV file and hit OPEN it gives the error `Application-Defined or Object-Defined Error`

Comment: Can you post the code from the whole `Sub` or `Function` ?

Answer (score 2):

`GetOpenFilename` will return the full *filespec* as a *String* variable.  You can parse it like:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim f As String, Path As String, _
        FileName As String, FileType As String

    f = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    MsgBox f

    ary = Split(f, "\")
    bry = Split(ary(UBound(ary)), ".")
    ary(UBound(ary)) = ""
    Path = Join(ary, "\")
    FileName = bry(0)
    FileType = bry(1)

    Range("A1") = Path
    Range("A2") = FileName
    Range("A3") = FileType
End Sub
```

[image]

and if you want to **pre-select** the path and filetype then:

```
Sub qwerty2()
    Dim f As String, Path As String, _
        FileName As String, FileType As String

    ChDir "C:\TestFolder"
    f = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Text Files (*.csv), *.csv")
    MsgBox f

    ary = Split(f, "\")
    bry = Split(ary(UBound(ary)), ".")
    ary(UBound(ary)) = ""
    Path = Join(ary, "\")
    FileName = bry(0)
    FileType = bry(1)

    Range("A1") = Path
    Range("A2") = FileName
    Range("A3") = FileType
End Sub
```

Comment: so you're "suspecting" that the "Application-Defined or Object-Defined Error" is not thrown right upon clicking the "Open" button when still in the "Open" dialog box?

Comment: @user3598756  Not sure.................the Dialog should itself not raise an error..........even if the file is protected or in some sense "hidden", the Dialog should return either the full filespec as a *String* or the *String* **False**

Comment: that's what I know, too. And that's what actually gives ground to "suspicions"...